# Why doesn't my dehumidifier stay on the humidity setting I select?

Tags: dehumidifier

This is my 40 pint dehumidifier. I need help setting the humidity it just keeps jumping to 76• and I need it at somewhere around 45•.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to set temperature or humidity? Bearing in mind that this is a dehumidifier, not an air conditioner ...

Answer (score 3):

You set a Relative Humidity value with a humidifier, not a temperature (as indicated on the control pad). The reason for your confusion may be that when you set some humidifiers, the set point is displayed for a short time, and then the actual RH is displayed on a long-term basis. You won't see the set RH again unless you adjust it.

Comment: And, depending on where the OP is and what space he's trying to dehumidify, the dehumidifier just may be too small for the job, so it never gets below 75% RH.

Comment: Yes, I would suspect this is what is happening...a few seconds after you set the target humidity, the display will change modes and show the current humidity.  @SheilaS, Depending on your region and basement conditions, you may not be able to reach 45%, but over the next few days you should see the current humidity gradually decline if you check on it a couple times a day.  Case in point, I have a 70pt dehumidifier in my 1200sf basement and over the past month the lowest I observed was 45% before it went back up to 50% and I readjusted my target humidity to something more realistic.